# Add a title to a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, indexing, rename

I originally had a dataframe `df1`,

```
                 Close                                                    
ticker            AAPL        AMD        BIDU        GOOGL          IXIC   
Date                                                                       
2011-06-01   12.339643   8.370000  132.470001   263.063049   2769.189941   
2011-06-02   12.360714   8.240000  138.490005   264.294281   2773.310059   
2011-06-03   12.265714   7.970000  133.210007   261.801788   2732.780029   
2011-06-06   12.072857   7.800000  126.970001   260.790802   2702.560059   
2011-06-07   11.858571   7.710000  124.820000   259.774780   2701.560059   
...                ...        ...         ...          ...           ...   
2021-05-24  127.099998  77.440002  188.960007  2361.040039  13661.169922   
2021-05-25  126.900002  77.860001  192.770004  2362.870117  13657.169922   
2021-05-26  126.849998  78.339996  194.880005  2380.310059  13738.000000   
2021-05-27  125.279999  78.419998  194.809998  2362.679932  13736.280273   
2021-05-28  124.610001  80.080002  196.270004  2356.850098  13748.740234
```

Due to the need for calculation, I changed the columns and created `df2`, which contains no `Close`,

```
ticker          AAPL       AMD      BIDU     GOOGL      IXIC
Date                                                                     
2011-08-25  0.760119  0.028203  0.621415  0.036067  0.993046
2011-09-23  0.648490  0.216017  0.267167  0.699657  0.562897
2011-10-21  0.442864  0.326310  0.197121  0.399332  0.048258
2011-11-18  0.333015  0.062089  0.164588  0.373293  0.015258
2011-12-19  0.101208  0.389120  0.218844  0.094759  0.116979
...              ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
2021-01-12  0.437177  0.012871  0.997870  0.075802  0.137392
2021-02-10  0.064343  0.178901  0.522356  0.625447  0.320007
2021-03-11  0.135033  0.300345  0.630085  0.253857  0.466884
2021-04-09  0.358583  0.484004  0.295894  0.215424  0.454395
2021-05-07  0.124987  0.311816  0.999940  0.232552  0.281189
```

And now I am struggling on how to add a name to the dataframe again, say `ret`, because I would like to plot the histogram of each column, and would like the titles to be something like `('ret', 'AAPL')`...

This may be a bit stupid and confusing, hopefully I have explained the question clearly. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure you can give a title to dataframe since it's just an object. You could however add a plot using matplotlib and give it a title there. Let me know if you need help with the plots.

Comment: I plot the histogram directly by `mydf.hist`, but the titles are 'AAPL', 'AMD', .... , and I would like to add a name before `AAPL`, `AMD`,.... Originally I had the `Close` when importing the csv. And I can change the `Close` by `df.rename(columns={'Close': 'ret'})`, but since I need to do some calculations, I created `df3` and `df4` and changed the columns by `df.columns = tickers`, my `df3` and df4` look just like `df2` in my question except for the numerical values. Now I am wondering that if there is any way that I could add the `Close` (or any other name) to my `df2` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) method:

```
df2=df2.set_index('Date')
#If 'Date' column is not your Index then make it index
df2.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['ret'],df2.columns])
```

Comment: Thank you. It did just what I want. And does this mean that `df2` has multiindex columns now?

Comment: @Lazer yes df2 has multiindex columns now